# python .bash_profile alias

Tags: python, macos, alias, bash

Im trying executing a python file from an alias (macosx).

It's possible?.

```
alias execute ='python path/file.py'
```

Im trying like this, but doesn't work, any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: It is not going to from another directories if you specify a relative path to `file.py`.

Comment: "doesn't work" is always a bad description of what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the space before the `=`, and it should work:

```
$ cat /tmp/x.py 
print 'hello, world!'

$ alias execute='python /tmp/x.py'
$ execute
hello, world!
```

Also note that I'm using the absolute path (`/tmp`). Using a relative path would make the command work in some directories, but not in others.